# SwiftUI onTapGesture does not work with ObservedObject in Mac app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I would like to update a view (RightView) based on actions from a tap gesture in another view (LeftView). Below is my example code to accomplish this:

**AppState.swift**

```
import Foundation

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tapCount: Int = 0

    func incrementTapCount() {
        self.tapCount += 1
        print("tap count \(self.tapCount)")
    }
}
```

**LeftView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LeftView: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Left View")
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("tapped left view")
            self.appState.incrementTapCount()
        }
    }
}
```

**RightView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct RightView: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Right View")
            Text("Tap Count: \(self.appState.tapCount)")
        }.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            LeftView()
            RightView()
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the RightView text does not update with the tap count. However, if I use a timer in the ObservableObject class to update the tap count, then the RightView updates correctly.

```
import Foundation

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tapCount: Int = 0

    init() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.tapCount += 1
        }
    }

    func incrementTapCount() {
        self.tapCount += 1
        print("tap count \(self.tapCount)")
    }
}
```

Why does the tap gesture in LeftView not update the RightView text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LeftView` and `RightView` are each initializing their own separate `AppState` objects, so they aren't observing the same state.

In both of your views, leave the `@ObservedObject` as an uninitialized property:

**LeftView.swift & RightView.swift**

```
@ObservedObject var appState: AppState
```

When you have an uninitialized property like this in a SwiftUI view, you need to provide a value for it any time you want to use the view.

The `PreviewProvider` uses an instance of your view so Xcode can show it to you on the canvas, and it only needs you to supply a *placeholder* value for `appState`. The value isn't really important (it isn't used anywhere but the Xcode canvas) so you just need to provide something of the correct type:

```
#if DEBUG
struct LeftView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LeftView(appState: AppState())
    }
}
#endif
```

Finally in `ContentView` you'll want to pass a reference to a single *shared* `AppState` down to `LeftView` and `RightView` so they can each observe the same object:

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var sharedAppState = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            LeftView(appState: sharedAppState)
            RightView(appState: sharedAppState)
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Now that both views are observing the same instance of `AppState`, they'll both update when its properties change.

You can also use `@EnvironmentObject` to share state between *all* the views in your app, but since we're only concerned with two views here `@ObservedObject` is a pragmatic choice.

Comment: Good catch, I completely missed the AppState initialization issue. Can you also show the changes needed to the PreviewProvider code for the LeftView and RightView?