# Passing data between two views

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I wanted to create quiet a simple app on watchOS 6, but after Apple has changed the ObjectBindig in Xcode 11 beta 5 my App does not run anymore. I simply want to synchronize data between two Views.

So I have rewritten my App with the new @Published, but I can't really set it up:

```
class UserInput: ObservableObject {

    @Published var score: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var input = UserInput()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World\(self.input.score)")
            Button(action: {self.input.score += 1})
                {
                    Text("Adder")
                }
            NavigationLink(destination: secondScreen()) {
                Text("Next View")
            }

        }

    }
}

struct secondScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var input = UserInput()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Button has been pushed \(input.score)")
            Button(action: {self.input.score += 1
            }) {
                Text("Adder")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I know that the release notes sites that `objectWillChange` will automatically be emitted, but it was only when I explicitly coded it that my stuff worked. Have you tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI onTapGesture does not work with ObservedObject in Mac app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348113/swiftui-ontapgesture-does-not-work-with-observedobject-in-mac-app)

Comment: You don't need an observable object as an @State Int will work as well.

Comment: Edited my answer with more details.

Comment: Use what superpuccio said or call `ContentView().environmentObject(UserInput())` and declare input as `@EnvironmentObject var input: User Input`, in which case the environment `.environmentObject`-call distributes the created object to all children.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635914/initialize-stateobject-with-a-parameter-in-swiftui/64964423#64964423

Answer (score 15):

Your code has a couple of errors:

1) You didn't put your `ContentView` in a `NavigationView`, so the navigation between the two views never happened.

2) You used data binding in a wrong way. If you need the second view to rely on some state belonging to the first view you need to pass a binding to that state to the second view. Both in your first view and in your second view you had an `@ObservedObject` created inline:

```
@ObservedObject var input = UserInput()
```

so, the first view and the second one worked with two totally different objects. Instead, you are interested in sharing the `score` between the views. Let the first view own the `UserInput` object and just pass a binding to the score integer to the second view. This way both the views will work on the same value (you can copy paste the code below and try yourself).

```
import SwiftUI

class UserInput: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var input = UserInput()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World\(self.input.score)")
                Button(action: {self.input.score += 1})
                    {
                        Text("Adder")
                    }
                NavigationLink(destination: secondScreen(score: self.$input.score)) {
                    Text("Next View")
                }

            }
        }

    }
}

struct secondScreen: View {
    @Binding var score:  Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Button has been pushed \(score)")
            Button(action: {self.score += 1
            }) {
                Text("Adder")
            }
        }

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

If you really need it you can even pass the entire `UserInput` object to the second view:

```
import SwiftUI

class UserInput: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var input = UserInput() //please, note the difference between this...
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World\(self.input.score)")
                Button(action: {self.input.score += 1})
                    {
                        Text("Adder")
                    }
                NavigationLink(destination: secondScreen(input: self.input)) {
                    Text("Next View")
                }

            }
        }

    }
}

struct secondScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var input: UserInput //... and this!
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Button has been pushed \(input.score)")
            Button(action: {self.input.score += 1
            }) {
                Text("Adder")
            }
        }

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: hey, would you mind explain how it works? the first example that score was passed to second view. score is value type. the value should be copied to second view. why would it affect the first view?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of different approaches on how to pass data from one view to another and came up with a solution that fits for simple and complex views / view models.

**Version**

```
Apple Swift version 5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.0.41 clang-1200.0.32.8)
```

This solution works with iOS 14.0 upwards, because you need the `.onChange()` view modifier. The example is written in Swift Playgrounds. If you need an `onChange` like modifier for lower versions, you should write your own modifier.

**Main View**

The main view has a `@StateObject viewModel` handling all of the views logic, like the button tap and the "data" `(testingID: String)` -> Check the ViewModel

```
struct TestMainView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.viewModel.didTapButton() }) {
                Text("TAP")
            }
            Spacer()
            SubView(text: $viewModel.testingID)
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 400)
    }
    
}
```

**Main View Model (ViewModel)**

The viewModel publishes a `testID: String?`. This testID can be any kind of object (e.g. configuration object a.s.o, you name it), for this example it is just a string also needed in the sub view.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var testingID: String?
    
    func didTapButton() {
        self.testingID = UUID().uuidString
    }
    
}
```

So by tapping the button, our `ViewModel` will update the `testID`. We also want this `testID` in our `SubView` and if it changes, we also want our `SubView` to recognize and handle these changes. Through the `ViewModel @Published var testingID` we are able to **publish** changes to our view. Now let's take a look at our **SubView** and **SubViewModel**.

**SubView**

So the `SubView` has its own `@StateObject` to handle its own logic. It is completely separated from other views and ViewModels. In this example the `SubView` only presents the testID from its `MainView`. But remember, it can be any kind of object like presets and configurations for a database request.

```
struct SubView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: SubviewModel = .init()
    
    @Binding var test: String?
    init(text: Binding<String?>) {
        self._test = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.viewModel.subViewText ?? "no text")
            .onChange(of: self.test) { (text) in
                self.viewModel.updateText(text: text)
            }
            .onAppear(perform: { self.viewModel.updateText(text: test) })
    }
}
```

To "connect" our `testingID` **published** by our `MainViewModel` we initialize our `SubView` with a `@Binding`. So now we have the same `testingID` in our `SubView`. But we don't want to use it in the view directly, instead we need to pass the data into our `SubViewModel`, remember our SubViewModel is a `@StateObject` to handle all the logic. And we can't pass the value into our `@StateObject` during view initialization. Also if the data (`testingID: String`) changes in our `MainViewModel`, our `SubViewModel` should recognize and handle these changes.

Therefore we are using two `ViewModifiers`.

**onChange**

```
.onChange(of: self.test) { (text) in
                self.viewModel.updateText(text: text)
            }
```

The **onChange** modifier subscribes to changes in our `@Binding` property. So if it **changes**, these changes get passed to our `SubViewModel`. Note that your property needs to be **Equatable**. If you pass a more complex object, like a `Struct`, make sure to **implement** this protocol in your `Struct`.

**onAppear**

We need `onAppear` to handle the "first initial data" because onChange doesn't fire the first time your view gets initialized. It is only for **changes**.

```
.onAppear(perform: { self.viewModel.updateText(text: test) })
```

Ok and here is the **SubViewModel**, nothing more to explain to this one I guess.

```
class SubviewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var subViewText: String?
    
    func updateText(text: String?) {
        self.subViewText = text
    }
}
```

Now your data is in sync between your **MainViewModel** and **SubViewModel** and this approach works for large views with many subviews and subviews of these subviews and so on. It also keeps your views and corresponding viewModels enclosed with high reusability.

**Working Example**

Playground on GitHub:
https://github.com/luca251117/PassingDataBetweenViewModels

**Additional Notes**

*Why I use `onAppear` and `onChange` instead of only `onReceive`: It appears that replacing these two modifiers with `onReceive` leads to a continuous data stream firing the `SubViewModel updateText` multiple times. If you need to stream data for presentation, it could be fine but if you want to handle network calls for example, this can lead to problems. That's why I prefer the "two modifier approach".*

*Personal Note: Please don't modify the StateObject outside the corresponding view's scope. Even if it is somehow possible, it is not what its meant for.*

Answer (score 0):

My question is still related to how to pass data between two views but I have a more complicated JSON data set and I am running into problems both with the passing the data and with it's initialization. I have something that works but I am sure it is not correct. Here is the code. Help!!!!

```
/ File: simpleContentView.swift
import SwiftUI
// Following is the more complicated @ObservedObject (Buddy and class Buddies)
struct Buddy : Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var TheirNames: TheirNames
    var dob: String = ""
    var school: String = ""
    enum CodingKeys1: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case Names = "Names"
        case dob = "dob"
        case school = "school"
    }
}
struct TheirNames : Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var first: String = ""
    var middle: String = ""
    var last: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys2: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case first = "first"
        case last = "last"
    }
}

class Buddies: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Buddy] {
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")}
        }
    }
    @Published var buddy: Buddy
    init() {
        if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([Buddy].self, from: items) {
                self.items = decoded
                // ??? How to initialize here
                self.buddy = Buddy(TheirNames: TheirNames(first: "c", middle: "r", last: "c"), dob: "1/1/1900", school: "hard nocks")
                return
            }
        }
        // ??? How to initialize here
        self.buddy = Buddy(TheirNames: TheirNames(first: "c", middle: "r", last: "c"), dob: "1/1/1900", school: "hard nocks")
        self.items = []
    }
}

struct simpleContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var showingSheet = true
    @ObservedObject var buddies = Buddies()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Simple View")
            Button(action: {self.showingSheet.toggle()}) {Image(systemName: "triangle")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                simpleDetailView(buddies: self.buddies, item: self.buddies.buddy)}
        }
    }
}

struct simpleContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        simpleContentView()
    }
}
// End of File: simpleContentView.swift
// This is in a separate file: simpleDetailView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct simpleDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var buddies = Buddies()
    var item: Buddy
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            Text("First Name = \(item.TheirNames.first)")
            Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}){ Text("return"); Image(systemName: "gobackward")}
        }
    }
}
// ??? Correct way to make preview call
struct simpleDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // ??? Correct way to call here
        simpleDetailView(item: Buddy(TheirNames: TheirNames(first: "", middle: "", last: ""), dob: "", school: "") )
    }
}
// end of: simpleDetailView.swift
```

Comment: since you have to complex struct to parse and handle, so that won't be possible with the State properties, you eventually have to use Published to achieve the desired behaviour. I have published my answer below, try that and see if it works for you or not. I have modified it for my own use with (i.e for codable structs.)

Answer (score 0):

Using directly @State variable will help you to achieve this, but if you want to sync that variable for both the screens using view model or @Published, this is what you can do. As the @State won't be binded to the @Published property. To achieve this follow these steps.

Step1: - Create a delegate to bind the value on pop or disappearing.

```
 protocol BindingDelegate {
     func updateOnPop(value : Int)
 }
```

Step 2:- Follow the code base for Content View

```
 class UserInput: ObservableObject {
      @Published var score: Int = 0
 }

 struct ContentView: View , BindingDelegate {

   @ObservedObject var input = UserInput()

   @State var navIndex : Int? = nil

   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
          VStack {
              Text("Hello World\(self.input.score)")
              Button(action: {self.input.score += 1}) {
                    Text("Adder")
                }

            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: secondScreen(score: self.$input.score,
                                                         del: self, navIndex: $navIndex),
                                                         tag: 1, selection: $navIndex) {
                    EmptyView()
                }

                Button(action: {
                    self.navIndex = 1
                }) {
                    Text("Next View")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

   func updateOnPop(value: Int) {
       self.input.score = value
   }
}
```

Step 3: Follow these steps for secondScreen

```
final class ViewModel : ObservableObject {

@Published var score : Int

   init(_ value : Int) {
       self.score = value
   }
}

struct secondScreen: View {

@Binding var score:  Int
@Binding var navIndex : Int?

@ObservedObject private var vm : ViewModel

var delegate  : BindingDelegate?

init(score : Binding<Int>, del : BindingDelegate, navIndex : Binding<Int?>) {
    self._score = score
    self._navIndex = navIndex
    self.delegate = del
    self.vm = ViewModel(score.wrappedValue)
}

private var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
    self.delegate?.updateOnPop(value: self.vm.score)
    self.navIndex = nil
}) {
    HStack {
        Text("Back")
    }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Button has been pushed \(vm.score)")
        Button(action: {
            self.vm.score += 1
        }) {
            Text("Adder")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)

   }
}
```