# How to change background color with ColorPicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, io

I am new to swiftUI, I have 2 views. I want that in AddTodoView using the ColorPicker I select a color, and in the ContentView this color is displayed in the background.

ContentView
`.background(AddTodoView().backgroundColor)`

AddTodoView
`@State var backgroundColor = Color(.systemBackground)`
`ColorPicker("Choosing a background color", selection: $backgroundColor)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57415086/3151675

Comment: It is somehow difficult for my task

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between views using a `@Binding`. Right now, by calling `AddTodoView().backgroundColor`, you're creating a *new instance* of `AddTodoView`, whereas you actually want to reference the value from the same view that exists in your hierarchy.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var backgroundColor : Color = Color(.systemBackground)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            backgroundColor //I'm using it in a ZStack, but you could also attach .background(backgroundColor) to any element in the hierarchy
            AddTodoView(backgroundColor: $backgroundColor)
        }
    }
}

struct AddTodoView : View {
    @Binding var backgroundColor: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        ColorPicker("Choose a color", selection: $backgroundColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: What value to write in AddTodoView(backgroundColor:  ***) 

```struct AddTodoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            AddTodoView(backgroundColor:  ) 
    }
}```

Comment: You could use `.constant(Color(.systemBackground))` or `.constant(Color.white)` or any `Color` you want wrapped in `.constant()`